# binary search program. giving correct output still showing ""Time Limit Exceeded"" Error while applying test cases

Tags: c++, search, time, limit

showing time exceeded while running.
please help me out.

```
  #include<stdio.h>

int BinarySearch(int l, int h, int *a, int x );
  int main()

{

  int a[10], n, i, x, r=1, q=0;

  int *p= &a[0];

  printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");

  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter the elements :\n");

  for(i=0; i<n; i++)

    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

  printf("Enter the element to be searched :\n");

  scanf("%d", &x);

 r=BinarySearch(q, n-1, p, x);



  if(r==-1)

    printf("The element %d is not present in the array\n", x);

  else

  printf("The element %d is in position %d", x, r);

 return 0;

}



int BinarySearch(int l, int h, int *a, int x)

{

  while(l<=h)

  {

    int m;

    m=(l+(h-1))/2;

    if (a[m]==x)

    return m;

    if(a[m]<x)

      l=m+1;

    else

      h=m-1;

  }
  return -1;
}
```

running and also giving correct output some times.

Comment: which input works, which does not? On which platform are you executing your program? Does it actually print "time exceeded"?

Comment: When you used a debugger, which statement is causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your BinarySearch function can enter infinite loop in certain cases, e.g. in this case:

```
int a[] = {1, 2}; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    BinarySearch(1, 1, a, 10);
    return 0;
}
```